# Python Pyparsing: Identify Pattern of Optional List + Keyword + Optional List

Tags: python, string, parsing, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse Csound opcode lines with Pyparser (to create a custom auto-formatter) and I'm stuck trying to define the following formula:

```
optional comma list + keyword + optional comma list
```

The possible variations of a Csound line of code:

```
        prints  "int: %d%n", 45
a1      oscil   0.5, 440, -1
aL, aR  stereo  a1
        outs    aL, aR
```

And their syntaxes:

```
                opcode  string, param
output          opcode  param, param, param
output, output  opcode  param
                opcode  param, param
```

So far I have come up with this:

```py
import pyparsing as pp

samples = [
    "prints \"int: %d%n\", 45",
    "a1 oscil 0.5, 440",
    "aL, aR stereo a1",
    "outs aL, aR"
]

var = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)

outputs = pp.Optional(pp.delimitedList(var))

opcode = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)

param = var | pp.dblQuotedString
params = pp.Optional(pp.delimitedList(param))

csound_line = outputs("outputs") \
    + opcode("opcode") \
    + params("params")

parsed = csound_line.parseString(samples[1])
print(parsed.dump())
parsed = csound_line.parseString(samples[2])
print(parsed.dump())
parsed = csound_line.parseString(samples[3])
print(parsed.dump())
parsed = csound_line.parseString(samples[0])
print(parsed.dump())
```

But it gives me this:

```
['a1', 'oscil', '0']
- opcode: 'oscil'
- outputs: ['a1']
- params: ['0']
['aL', 'aR', 'stereo', 'a1']
- opcode: 'stereo'
- outputs: ['aL', 'aR']
- params: ['a1']
['outs', 'aL']
- opcode: 'aL'
- outputs: ['outs']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oliver/projects/personal/local/csoundformat/./test.py", line 33, in <module>
    parsed = csound_line.parseString(samples[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1955, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 3250, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected W:(ABCD...), found '"'  (at char 7), (line:1, col:8)
```

Parsing line 2 works correctly, but lines 1 and 3 are missing end parameters and line 0 causes a complaint about double quotes, despite my using `dblQuotedString`.

I just can't seem to nail down the right combination of `Optional`/`ZeroOrMore` and `delimitedList`. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of notes before answering the core question:

1. I found it quite confusing that you list the input samples in a different order from the execution runs. I guess I understand why you ran them in that order -- although a `try` block would have solved the problem -- but it would have been a lot more reader-friendly to just reorder the input list. Just sayin', for future reference.)
2. The `oscil` line cuts off early because your `param` only recognises alphanumerics and quoted strings. Unsigned integers are made up of `alphanums`, but since `.` is not an alphanum, floating point numbers like `0.5` don't match. `pp.Word(pp.alphanums)` stops after the `0`.

   You'd run into a similar problem with `-1`, with the difference that there is no previous digit which could be matched.

---

The fundamental problem, though, is that the grammar is ambiguous unless you have a way of distinguishing an output variable from an opcode. Without that, `a b` can be parsed either as `output(a) opcode(b) param()` or `output() opcode(a) param(b)`.

Pyparsing's `optional` is greedy, so `pp.optional(outputs)` will parse the first `var` token as a one-element `outputs`. That means that it would parse `a b` as `outputs(a) opcode(b) params()`, which resolves the ambiguity but doesn't always produce the correct parse. It will do that even in cases where it is obviously wrong (to a human observer who can see the entire command), such as the commands `op` or `op "foo"`. That fact that `op` will be parsed as an output, not an opcode, means that both of those will produce syntax errors. (That's the problem with the `prints` command.)

So to parse a line, it's necessary to distinguish between the following cases (I use `[...]` to indicate optional):

```
a , ...    => a is an output, ... is (more) outputs followed by opcode [params]
a b , ...  => a is an opcode, b is a param, ... is more params
a b c ...  => a is an output, b is an opcode, ... is [, params]
a b        => ambiguous. Either output opcode or opcode param.
a          => a is an opcode (and nothing follows)
```

That's only an approximation, because a param could be a quoted string, a number, or (I suppose) an expression. I think the grammar below will correctly handle that case, but you'll need to expand the definition of `param` in order to try it.

It would probably be more efficient to combine the third and fourth cases by using an `opt_params` instead of `params`; you can then detect the ambiguous case by the absence of params. But I left it like this to make the ambiguity clearer.

```
var = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)

outputs = pp.delimitedList(var)
opt_outputs = pp.Optional(outputs)

opcode = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)

# Note: Probably need to add expressions. I added a very simple
# floating point syntax, but it doesn't handle signs. (It has to go first
# in order to avoid 'var' matching the initial integer.)
param = pp.Combine(pp.Word(pp.nums) + '.' + pp.Word(pp.nums)) \
        | var \
        | pp.dblQuotedString

params = pp.delimitedList(param)
opt_params = pp.Optional(params)

comma = pp.Suppress(',')

csound_line = ( (var + comma + outputs)("outputs")
                + opcode("opcode")
                + opt_params("params")
              ) | (
                opcode("opcode") + (param + comma + params)("params")
              ) | (
                pp.And((var,))("outputs") + opcode("opcode") + params("params")
              ) | (
                (var + var)("ambiguous")
              ) | (
                opcode("opcode") + opt_params("params")
              )
```

(The use of `pp.And((var,))` is to put the single output token into a list, for consistency with the other `outputs` parses. There might well be a better way to do that.)

Note that pyparsing's `parseString` does not insist on parsing to the end of the input, which is why some of your test cases failed silently. I think it's better for failures to be explicit, so I added `parseAll` to the call. I also put a `try` block around it, to make the test a little easier to write:

```
samples = """
    prints "int: %d%n", 45
    a1 oscil 0.5, 440
    aL, aR stereo a1
    outs aL, aR
    output opcode param
    opcode param
    output opcode
    opcode
"""
for sample in samples.splitlines()[1:]:
    print(sample)
    try:
        print(csound_line.parseString(sample, parseAll=True).dump())
    except pp.ParseException as e:
        print("Parse failed:")
        print(e)
    print('-----------------------')
```

Here's the test output:

```
    prints "int: %d%n", 45
['prints', '"int: %d%n"', '45']
- opcode: 'prints'
- params: ['"int: %d%n"', '45']
-----------------------
    a1 oscil 0.5, 440
['a1', 'oscil', '0.5', '440']
- opcode: 'oscil'
- outputs: ['a1']
- params: ['0.5', '440']
-----------------------
    aL, aR stereo a1
['aL', 'aR', 'stereo', 'a1']
- opcode: 'stereo'
- outputs: ['aL', 'aR']
- params: ['a1']
-----------------------
    outs aL, aR
['outs', 'aL', 'aR']
- opcode: 'outs'
- params: ['aL', 'aR']
-----------------------
    output opcode param
['output', 'opcode', 'param']
- opcode: 'opcode'
- outputs: ['output']
- params: ['param']
-----------------------
    opcode param
['opcode', 'param']
- ambiguous: ['opcode', 'param']
-----------------------
    output opcode
['output', 'opcode']
- ambiguous: ['output', 'opcode']
-----------------------
    opcode
['opcode']
- opcode: 'opcode'
-----------------------
```

Comment: I have written so many of those "loop through these test cases and try-except calling parseString with parseAll=True and print the results or the exception" methods that I finally added `runTests` to `ParserElement`. See how `csound_line.runTests(samples)` works for you (don't even have to call `splitlines()`).

Comment: Wow! Thank you, this is an awesome explanation of my problem! I didn't think to combine multiple cases in `csound_line`, which is very clever. And you're right, the syntax is annoyingly ambiguous with opcode/param and output/opcode lines. Perhaps I will treat them as their own "ambiguous" category and format them accordingly. The alternative would be to create some sort of database of the opcode definitions from the Csound documentation (a scarily large undertaking). Thank you again, this was both an eye-opener and an enjoyable read!